# No Gradients For tf.one_hot

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a custom loss function that has an output of an integer (which is converted to one hot encoding in the loss function).

But the problem is that one_hot does not have differentiable gradients.
Are there any workarounds?

```
def new_loss(hidden, output, random_size=20):

    output1 = tf.cast(
        output,
        dtype=tf.int32,
    )
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(output1, num_words, dtype=tf.int32,)

    one_hot = tf.cast(
        one_hot,
        dtype=tf.float32
    )

    score = K.dot(hidden, one_hot)
    random_words = tf.random.uniform((random_size,), maxval=num_words, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
    random_words_1_hot = tf.one_hot(random_words, num_words, dtype=tf.float32)
    scores = K.dot(random_words_1_hot, hidden)
    average = K.sum(K.log (1 - K.sigmoid(scores)) / random_size)

    return (-1 * K.log (K.sigmoid(score)) - average)
```

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Comment: The way I see it, your OneHot is directly based on the integer before it, which is differentiable, if I have got that wrong, post a rough layout of the model and I will let you know, my basic point is if the result is just getting one-hot encoded, it doesn't need a gradient, gradients are for activation steps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in one_hot encoding itself, but rather in series of cast operations. More specifically, TensorFlow won't propagate through integers. Assuming both `hidden` and `output` is of type float, if you change this

```py
output1 = tf.cast(output, dtype=tf.int32,)
one_hot = tf.one_hot(output1, num_words, dtype=tf.int32,)

one_hot = tf.cast(one_hot, dtype=tf.float32)
```

to this

```
one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(output, tf.int32), num_words, dtype=tf.float32)
```

You'll get your gradients.

More detailed example:

```py
one_hot1 = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(np.random.rand(2), tf.int32), num_words, dtype=tf.float32)
hidden = tf.constant([1.,2.,3.,4.], shape=(2,2))

one_hot = tf.cast(one_hot1, dtype=tf.float32)

hidden1 = tf.cast(hid, tf.float32)
score = tf.matmul(hidden, one_hot)
random_words = tf.random.uniform((random_size,), maxval=num_words, dtype=tf.float32)
random_words_1_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(random_words, tf.int32), num_words, dtype=tf.float32)
scores = tf.matmul(random_words_1_hot, hidden)
average = tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(1 - tf.sigmoid(scores)) / random_size)

res = -1 * tf.log(tf.sigmoid(score)) - average
grads = tf.gradients(res, [hidden1, one_hot1])
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(res))
print(sess.run(grads))
```

I used core TF operation just for the sake of consistency. You can see that if `one_hot1` will be initially created as `tf.int` and then recast to `float`, there'll be no gradient. More about this here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20524 
And