# Custom Tensorflow loss function with one hot encoding is generating vanishingly low gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I have implemented a custom cross entropy loss method in the following two ways,

```py
def custom_cross_entropy_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_logsumexp(y_pred, axis=-1) - tf.reduce_sum(y_pred * tf.one_hot(y_true, depth=10), axis=-1)
    )
```

and

```py
def custom_cross_entropy_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_logsumexp(y_pred, axis=-1) - tf.gather(y_pred, tf.cast(y_true, tf.int32), batch_dims=1)
    )
```

Following is a code segment to run these two loss functions,

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def custom_cross_entropy_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_logsumexp(y_pred, axis=-1) - tf.reduce_sum(y_pred * tf.one_hot(y_true, depth=10), axis=-1)
    )

def custom_cross_entropy_loss1(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_logsumexp(y_pred, axis=-1) - tf.gather(y_pred, tf.cast(y_true, tf.int32), batch_dims=1)
    )


model1 = keras.Sequential(layers=[
    layers.Input(shape=(28,28)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(units=10)
])

model1.compile(
    loss=custom_cross_entropy_loss,
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255

history = model1.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)

model2 = keras.Sequential(layers=[
    layers.Input(shape=(28,28)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(units=10)
])

model2.compile(
    loss=custom_cross_entropy_loss1,
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255

history = model2.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)
```

The outputs are as follows,

```
Epoch 1/2
750/750 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 2.3024 - accuracy: 0.1295 - val_loss: 2.3021 - val_accuracy: 0.1202
Epoch 2/2
750/750 [==============================] - 1s 932us/step - loss: 2.3012 - accuracy: 0.1204 - val_loss: 2.3017 - val_accuracy: 0.1617
Epoch 1/2
750/750 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.3525 - accuracy: 0.9012 - val_loss: 0.1919 - val_accuracy: 0.9471
Epoch 2/2
750/750 [==============================] - 1s 896us/step - loss: 0.1690 - accuracy: 0.9505 - val_loss: 0.1408 - val_accuracy: 0.9583
```

We can see that the model is not training properly in with the first function, but working with the second function.

Both the methods are identical in the results they produce. I have added the following code segment and it's output to verify that,

```py
print("Model 1")
print("Library Loss", keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(y_test[:3], model1(x_test[:3])))
print("Custom loss", custom_cross_entropy_loss(y_test[:3], model1(x_test[:3])))
print("Custom loss1", custom_cross_entropy_loss1(y_test[:3], model1(x_test[:3])))

print("\nModel 2")
print("Library Loss", keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(y_test[:3], model2(x_test[:3])))
print("Custom loss", custom_cross_entropy_loss(y_test[:3], model2(x_test[:3])))
print("Custom loss1", custom_cross_entropy_loss1(y_test[:3], model2(x_test[:3])))
```

Output:

```
Model 1
Library Loss tf.Tensor(2.1898634, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Custom loss tf.Tensor(2.1898634, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Custom loss1 tf.Tensor(2.1898634, shape=(), dtype=float32)

Model 2
Library Loss tf.Tensor(0.0041048857, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Custom loss tf.Tensor(0.0041049323, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Custom loss1 tf.Tensor(0.0041049323, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Even though the output of both the methods are exactly the same, for some reason the first method is producing vanishingly small gradient, but the second one works fine. I found this [No Gradients For tf.one_hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55482146/no-gradients-for-tf-one-hot) . But here the answer says casting to int is the problem. But in the first method I have not done any casting and funnily that's the one that is failing.

So I wanted to know the general reason why this is happening, and how to identify which tf functions can cause this kind of issues.

Comment: your problem is not in one_hot since you are using it over the target, thus there is no notion of "gradient" on that part

Comment: can you please post a minimal reproducible example? is this loss used in a Keras model inside the fit function or are you using gradient tape?

Comment: I didn't exactly follow what you mean by minimal reproducible scenario. You mean, I should add more code (conservatively enough) so that one can take that code and execute? Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly, produce a small snipped of code that allows us to reproduce the error (idk, a input tensor, a 1 layer NN for that tenor, the target tensor, the training loop)

Comment: I have adding the code segment. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this, but the error is somewhere else, I've just copy pasted the snipped and tried the 2 losses, and both of them works fine

Comment: Obviously not. You are probably making some mistake. I will add the whole file and output then to show the difference then.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue @samarendrachandanbinduDash is talking about. Not sure of the solution yet.

Comment: The issue can be observed [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AHlPjxMpc3zP7-jHKW75Ktu95nAXl3qx#scrollTo=XTIaXNqgq0Cc).

Comment: I really not able to reproduce the error ahah even with the colab posted, there is no error on my end : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417421013191 how do I have to tell you

Comment: as you can see, there is no error thrown, thus the gradient exists and it's been properly calculated, the fact that the gradient IS ALMOST ZERO (as the loss decreases very slowly),  it's a whole another question

Comment: Hi @AlbertoSinigaglia , yes you are correct. I was thinking the small changes were due to the data being shuffled, but that doesn't seem to be the case. If actually no gradient was being produced then it wouldn't have started training in the first place. I will update the question. Please let me know if you have a solution for it. Because when calculating with some given values, both the methods produce the exact same answer. So the implementation is not wrong. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash are the two implementations meant to be equivalent?

Comment: I am trying to implement the cross entropy loss. The method 1 was my first implementation. But it didn't produce gradients properly so went with the second implementation. So my doubt here is if both function are giving the exact same output then why there is difference in the gradient produced. Does that answer your question? @AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: what has `reduce_logsumexp` to do with crossentropy?

Comment: I am applying the loss on softmax logits. So if the denominator upon applying log becomes a "log" of "sum" of "exps" . Pardon me, but why you have this doubt? As I have already demonstrated (via comparing with library function) that my implementation is correct. So how will knowing what reduce_logsumexp is for will help debug the issue? When especially both the methods use reduce_logsumexp. If you are trying to isolate the error then probably one should focus on the differences between these methods.